# helper vs controller performace in laravel 5.*

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, helper, php-7.1

Lets assume I have a `helper` called **`engine`**.

```
if( ! function_exists('engine') )
{
    function engine($user_id_1, $user_id_2, $league, $log = true)
    {
        /*
         * variables
         */
        $questionsLevel = 1;

        $user1 = \App\User::where('id', $user_id_1)->first();
        $user2 = \App\User::where('id', $user_id_2)->first();

        $league = \App\Models\League::where('id', $league)->first();

        $users = $league->all_users;

        /*
         * check if users joined to league correctly
         */
         $user1_ok = $user2_ok = false;
         foreach($users as $user)
         {

             if( $user->id == $user_id_1 )
             {
                 $user1_ok = true;
             }
             if( $user->id == $user_id_2)
             {
                 $user2_ok = true;
             }

             $check_users = [
                 $user1_ok,
                 $user2_ok
             ];
         }

        if( in_array(false, $check_users) )
        {
            return [
                'errcode' => 404,
                'errmessage' => 'one ro both user/s did not joined to league'
            ];
        }

       //DO SOME STUFF

    }//function engine
}
```

As you know, I can write a `controller` to do same.

Does anyone know Which is faster based on Laravel architecture? and how can I test performance in both cases?

I'm using `laravel 5.7.*`

Comment: im not sure what you're asking. A controller method is to be used with a HTTP request. A helper can be used anywhere in the code. The same bootstrap is called if you are responding to a HTTP request anyway.

Comment: Both "approaches" are equally slow since you're querying the database. That adds the most time, therefore fiddling with microoptimizations won't get you anywhere, it's a waste of effort.

Answer (score 2):

Fastest would be a solution that does not load unnecessary data:

```
if(! function_exists('engine'))
{
    function engine(int $user1, int $user2, int $league)
    {
        return League::query()
            ->where('id', $league)
            ->whereHas('users', function($query) use ($user1) {
                $query->where('id', $user1);
            })
            ->whereHas('users', function($query) use ($user2) {
                $query->where('id', $user2);
            })
            ->exists();
    }
}
```

In general, I don't think such a function should return complex results like an error message though. For this particular job, you should use a controller action. The helper method should only return `true` or `false` in my opinion. You could also place the same logic in a service class though (probably the best solution).

Comment: I think you should change `use ($user)` to `use ($user1)`.

Comment: By the way how `id` will be both `$user1` and `$user2` ?

Comment: On a funny note your code is super fast now as it will always return false 

Answer (score 1):

About the performance, I do not think there will be any changes as same query will be executed as well as same number of operation will be done, for example the `foreach()` loop it is `O(n)` in both the cases, so what will be difference, but you may like to change your code to something like below or may use ternary operator also. The difference will be in organization of codes. In controller the testing will be easier.

Note: But how `id` will be both `$user1` and `$user2`, so let's make it OR in stead of AND

```
foreach($users as $user)
 {
     if( $user->id == $user_id_1 )
     {
         $user1_ok = true;
     }elseif( $user->id == $user_id_2)
     {
         $user2_ok = true;
     }

     $check_users = [
         $user1_ok,
         $user2_ok
    ];
}
```

to

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
    if( in_array($user->id, [$user_id_1, $user_id_2])
    {
        $user1_ok = true;
    }

    $check_users = [
        $user1_ok,
        $user2_ok
    ];
}
```

or

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
    if( $user->id == $user_id_1 )
    {
        $check_users['user1_ok'] = $user->id == $user_id_1 ? true : false;
    }
    if( $user->id == $user_id_2)
    {
        $check_users['user2_ok'] = true;
    }
}
```

If you want to get enginees with `user1_ok`, `user2_ok`, you may like to run a query as @Namoshek has suggested.

or you may like to change the query to something like

```
League::query()->where('id', $league)
        ->whereHas('users', function($query) use ($user1, $user2) {
            $query->where('id', $user1)->where('id', $user2);
    })->exists();
```

but, how id will be both $user1 and $user2?so, if it is OR instead of AND.

```
League::query()->where('id', $league)
    ->whereHas('users', function($query) use ($user1, $user2) {
        $query->whereIn('id', [$user1, $user2]);
})->exists();
```

or even `$users = [$user1, $user2];` and

```
League::query()->where('id', $league)
    ->whereHas('users', function($query) use ($users) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $users);
})->exists();
```

By the way, if you want this using these query, you just may put it in Engine model and user or reuse it when ever required. Also for helper, it can be reusable where as in controller it is not.

Comment: Copying answers is one thing. But changing them to something that returns wrong results is another.

Comment: @Namoshek I thought your code can be written differently, so I mentioned your name and rewritten how I thought it could be.

Comment: I see, but it can't. Your version doesn't ensure both users are part of the league.

Comment: @Namoshek if you think that will give wrong result, point out it, so that it will be helpful to me as well as others.

Comment: @Namoshek you are correct, it is just like orWhere() , you are correct.